# Error Downloading .obj file from Server: Too much unrecognized data in file, can't parse

Tags: swift, scenekit, .obj

I am trying to display a 3D model (from server URL) in my iOS application. But to do this, I need to download it locally first.

I am able to successfully do this with `.usdz` files but I need to be able to do it with `.obj` files. Here's how I am downloading the file:

```
guard let remote3dURL = URL(string: "https://github.com/Viktoo/Insert3D/blob/master/Example/Insert3D/model/Nachos.obj") else {
        return
    }
    do {
        let data3D = try Data(contentsOf: remote3dURL)
        let arURL = FileManager().temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Nachos.obj")
        try data3D.write(to: arURL!, options: .atomic)
    } catch {
        print("WTFCATCH")
    }
```

Immediately after downlading the file I get this error in console:

> Too much unrecognized data in file, can't parse

Why can't Swift Parse .obj files from server? Is it impossible or do I need to do it differently.

Comment: `print("WTFCATCH")` print the `error`. What's the size of the file? Also, what about using `URLSession`?

Comment: URLSession same result so far, also the catch block is actually never executed. Size of the file is < 10mb @Larme

Comment: It unclear. You aren't parsing anything, you are just manipulating data. Is the issue really there, or when you use the data read?